# Move files from subfolders to parent folders cmd powershell

Tags: powershell, file, move

I have been trying to move files from multiple subfolders to their parent folders by running the following .bat and .ps1 scripts:

```
1.  forfiles /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c move @path %CD%"
2. powershell -Command "gci *.* -R | mv -D ."
3. Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination .
4. Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination ..
```

The folders structure is 'Top folder' and two subfolders: Top_folder\Subfolder_1\Subfolder_2. The aim is to run script from main 'top folder' and having all the files from Subfolder_2 moved to Subfolder_1. The main folder have a numerous

```
Subfolder_1\Subfolder_2
Subfolder_1\Subfolder_2
...
Subfolder_1\Subfolder_2
```

folders. The above codes move files either to the current folder where script locates or into parent folder (up from the script location), depends on wildcard '..' or '.'

Any thoughts/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get the parent folder's literal name (full path) first, stick that in a variable, then use that in your destination call.

Comment: @postanote Thank you for your reply. I am afraid using the full path is not feasible, due to their number (hundreds folders) and uniquely naming of folders (Subfolder_1/_2)

Comment: Looking at your example commands, you appear to be selecting all files and directories in the current directory tree. You don't really want that, you want to select all files within each of the children of the current directory. _(Especially as the intended destination directory would already be the root of the source directory)_.

Comment: @SAM, you can dynamically grab that each time the script is run using the OS default to do so, i.e., using ```$PSScriptRoot```. This grabs the directory from where the script was executed, and you just ask for the ```parent```.

Comment: @Compo, postanote Thank you for the follow up. Would it be possible to show examples, please. I could not make it work.

Comment: "I could not make it work" is not a satisfactory programming problem description. Please show your attempts, and fully explain how they are failing to achieve what they are written to do. This is not a free code writing service, and after almost four months we'd expect to see much more.

Comment: @Compo, I have tried to change the original code 'Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination' by replacing '-Destination' with '-path' to their respective parent folders. However, I could not define/write the code to get this path (something if understood right like advised @_postanote 'ask for the 'parent').  Some of the attempts were to limit/filter output by attribute/operator -exclude and !Directory, also looked into utilising 'Resolve-Path -Relative'...

Comment: The comment section is not where you provide that information. There is an [Edit] button available for updating your submission with everything we need.

Comment: @Compo, it is done. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: No, @Sam, it isn't, I've rolled it back to the previous question version. Essentially you were asking a completely new question. Not only is that not the way we do that, we submit a new question, but nobody will be motivated to respond to it when an answer has already been accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution has been kindly provided by @francishagyard2 [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2236930-way-to-move-all-files-from-multiple-levels-of-sub-folders)

```
# Root path is referenced to script's location by means of variable $PSScriptRoot. That's how I use ones in most cases.
$RootPath = $PSScriptRoot

# Get list of parent folders in root path
$ParentFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath | Where {$_.PSIsContainer}

# For each parent folder get all files recursively and move to parent, append number to file to avoid collisions
ForEach ($Parent in $ParentFolders) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Parent.FullName -Recurse | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.DirectoryName -ne $Parent.FullName)} | ForEach {
        $FileInc = 1
        Do {
            If ($FileInc -eq 1) {$MovePath = Join-Path -Path $Parent.FullName -ChildPath $_.Name}
            Else {$MovePath = Join-Path -Path $Parent.FullName -ChildPath "$($_.BaseName)($FileInc)$($_.Extension)"}
            $FileInc++
        }
        While (Test-Path -Path $MovePath -PathType Leaf)
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $MovePath
    }
}
```